# JSDoc function returning a parameter of itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc, code-documentation

I need to document a function returning conditionally one of its parameters. But JSDoc seems not to accept variables as a return value.

I tried to do something like this following the return type `{1 | 0}` logic

```
/**
 * Finds the page with given index and returns
 *  - index if it does not exist
 *  - user if user doesn't have permissions to read
 *  - else the page itself 
 * 
 * @param {number} index 
 * @param {string} user 
 * @returns {index|user|Page}
 */
function getRead(index, user) {
    let page = pages.find(page => page.details.index == index);
    if (page && page.canRead(user)) {
        return page;
    } else if (!page) return index;
    else return user;
}
```

But it is not recognized and the return values is just `any`, if i use `{string|number|Page}` as type, afterwards in my code I do something like this

```
if(page == index) return res.send(`Page ${index} does not exist`);
if(page == user) return res.send(`No permissions to view page ${index}`);
//page still recognized as number | string | Page
//no code completion or property suggestions on page
```

I also tried to add type checks to get there but i don't want to believe that like such a lazy the solution is the only one, there must be a better way to handle this

```
if(typeof page == "number" || page == index) return res.send(`Page ${index} does not exist`);
if(typeof page == "string" || page == user) return res.send(`No permissions to view page ${index}`);
//page recognized as Page
```

Comment: "*there must be a better way to handle this*" - just don't return three different types?

Comment: Btw, being able to see which pages exist and which don't, without having permission to see them, could be a security issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions:

1. Use generic types for parameters

```
/**
 * Finds the page with given index and returns
 *  - index if it does not exist
 *  - user if user doesn't have permissions to read
 *  - else the page itself 
 * 
 * @template {number} IndexType
 * @template {string} UserType
 * @param {IndexType} index 
 * @param {UserType} user 
 * @returns {IndexType|UserType|Page}
 */
function getRead(index, user) {
 ...
}
```

[image]

2. Remove JSDoc for the function at all and rely on TypeScript's type inference

```
function getRead(/**@type {number}*/index, /**@type {string}*/user) {
  ...
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, it is just the right solution, i tried it too with literal values but with variables it doesn't work... Still getting the same issue [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/KrviO3B.png)